# Java ServerSocket won't accept new connections until close() is called on the accepted socket

Tags: java, sockets

In my code (below) the the serverSocket won't accept a new connection until a thread deals with the existing connection and calls close() on the socket that serverSocket.accept() created. If i start this server and open two tabs in the browser then only one of the tabs connects and the other is left waiting until the other tab finishes (which it doesn't) before serverSocket.accept() will accept a new connection. How can i accept a new connection without closing the previous one?

```
public class ReboundServer {

    static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public static boolean listening = true;

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {     
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);

            System.out.println("Starting Server");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
            System.exit(-1);
        }       

        while(listening)
        {
            (new Thread(new ClientThread(serverSocket.accept()))).start();
        }

        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    private Socket clientSocket = null;

    public ClientThread(Socket socket)
    {
        this.clientSocket = socket;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("ClientConnected");
        MatchThread.QueueLock.lock();
        MatchThread.connectionQueue.add(clientSocket);
        MatchThread.QueueLock.unlock(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Your server `accept()` loop looks fine to me; the behavior you describe is definitely not the expected behavior for this code. The behavior you want is the one you should be seeing. Perhaps there's some kind of a bottleneck in other code you're not showing us?

Comment: Alright, i've just pasted your code into an editor, and replaced your MatchThread.xxx call block with a simply infinite loop (so the thread doesnt end), and it works as you are expecting - I can connect multiple clients to the server. Therefore there could be a problem with MatchThread (possible, but unlikely) or there could be a problem with your environment. What OS are you working in? Are you using the Sun JDK or OpenJDK, or some other JRE?

Comment: Aha, I thought very much that it could just be my environment that is causing the problem. Thank you so much for testing. I'm going to go see if it works on a different machine.

Comment: Two windows 7 computers with Sun JDK (latest version) produce the same result where no more than 1 client can connect at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the problem is not here but in the MatchThread class whose code you haven't posted. It appears you have a single thread dealing with that queue. Why?

Comment: All the thread does is match up two clients and connects them together (currently it spins waiting for more than 2 clients and then closes them both)

Comment: @ntkachov That doesn't tell us enough to debug the problem, does it? What do you mean by 'connects them together' for example?